# Python Typechecking versus TypedDicts?

Tags: design-patterns, python, functions, type-systems

From what I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74850581/7437143) answer, it is not possible to use a typeddict and typechecking in a function. So for example, if one has a function:

```py
def some_func(some_int: int, some_dict:Custom_typed_dict) -> str:
    """
    Takes a value from dict and adds it to some_int and converts
    the result into a string.
    """
    new_int: int = some_dict["the_int"] + some_int
    return str(new_int)
```

One cannot apply the decorator `@typechecked` above `some_func` because it takes in the typeddict `some_dict:Custom_typed_dict` as argument. However, I would like to verify the `some_int` is correctly typed (using `@typechecked`).

So I would like to ask:

1. Is it a bad design pattern to have other return types and or argument types if one takes in a typed dictonary?/What would be a better design pattern?
2. Am I misunderstanding that it is not possible to type check the `some_int` whilst also type checking the typed dict argument?

### Note

I am aware that in the example, one can say: *"just pass `some_dict["the_int"]` directly instead of the entire dictionary"*, however, I also have functions that perform more complicated operations that use a larger fraction of the dictionary.

An alternative hypothesis is that I should not be using dictionaries for such non-homogeneous datastructures that one needs a typed dictionary.

Comment: Where does this `@typechecked` annotation come from? It is not part of Python's type system.

Comment: The `@typechecked` decorator comes from [typeguard](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html) .

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is better over at SO or not.  I don't think there's really a design pattern question here, or I'm not sure what it is, anyway.  Are you familiar with Pydantic, BTW?  I think it would address your needs here.